# Visual Studio Hangs while installing NuGet

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

When i try to install a particular package VS 15 hangs, and it took more than half an hour to complete the installation. But the same package is installed in VS13 within 2 mins and there is no problem with it. I have tried almost all version of NuGet package manager of VS15.

Comment: Did you install the Update 1 for VS2015 ? I don't have any problem with the latest VS2015 updates

Comment: Yes My VS is updated one, but still am facing this issue.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: I have VS2017. Nuget worked well until yesterday, when it started freezing of installing forever. I updated VS2017 to the lastest 15.8.5. I rebooted the computer. I loaded a small sample project, and tried to install a small Nuget packages... stuck!

Comment: i experienced the same error on vs 2015 14.0.25123.00 update 2. 
But now it's okay using nuget package manager after i tried to open it as administrator. :D Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, here are the following steps I did to minimize the issue:

- Use the Package Manager console instead of Manage Nuget package when installing packages. (i.e. install-nuget )
- Make sure the package is not yet existing on the packages folder of Visual Studio solution.
- Make sure the package is not also existing in Content and Scripts folder of your Solution Explorer
- Run your Visual Studio 2015 in Administrator mode.

When I use the Manage Nuget Package, my VS 2015 Update 3 will just hangs up, then ultimately will end up not responding even though I will leave it even for 2 hours! Certainly there is an issue, but the above steps speed's up the installation though it might take until 10 minutes to finish the installation.

Comment: I discovered when using the Package Manager that it was hung up because some dependencies weren't compatible with the version of .Net Core I had installed. Once I figured this out, I was able to install a lower version from the package manager with no problems.

Comment: for me it just stop loading... but visual studio still running. It just stuck. any other solutions?